# addEventListner is not working second time

Tags: javascript

So I have this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/u73azkLd/1/

I want to make a question generator.

I have that eventListner on **+qustion** button. Everything is working fine, until the eventListner is finished.

After that, If I want to add another question, after I'm presing **+question** button, the Question? input appears and after that I can't click on **Continue** button. I don't get any error in console.

My english is bad and I can't describe it better than that.

Click on +question, click on Continue, after that click on Continue again. Now I want to add another question, so let's click again on +question button and after that the continue button is not working.

I tryed this:
on line 23,24,25:

```
var ctnBtn1 = document.getElementById("ctnBtn1");
    ctnBtn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (e.target && e.target.id == "ctnBtn1") <- This is what i tryed and is not working.
    ctnBtn1.style.display = "none";
    etc ....
```

Comment: Why are you testing the ID of the target? You're setting the listener specifically on the element, you shouldn't need to check the ID.

Comment: Please provide your HTML and use a JS/CSS/HTML Code Snippet that can be run, that will help people answer your question

Comment: Problem is this statement --> `var ctnBtn1 = document.getElementById("ctnBtn1");` You already have a `Continue` button created and stored in `continueBtnQuestion` variable. You don't need to access the DOM and get the button with the id of `ctnBtn1`. Because doing so will give you the first `Continue` button instead of the newly created one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just hide the button instead of removing it. In result when you search for a button with given id you get the first one (the one that is already hidden).

You can replace `ctnBtn1.style.display = "none";` with

```
ctnBtn1.parentNode.removeChild(ctnBtn1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much <3333